# How to keep my cat out of the neighbors' house?

Tags: cats

Over the last couple of days, our beloved cat has taken to invading the neighbors' house, and literally sleeping in their bed (under the covers!), or tearing holes through their window screens so she can get out.

The neighbors are understandably furious; they are decidedly not cat-lovers, and one of them is allergic.

We cannot keep all our doors and windows permanently closed. We either need a watertight (or cat-tight) solution, or we need to get rid of our cat. :-(

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I get the impression that part of the responsibility of this problem lies on the neighbor, since, especially if they don't have their own cats, their home should be secure enough to keep the cat out.  If a cat can get in, then all kinds of pretty large wildlife can also get in, so for their own security they should be improving their own home to keep out animals.  But at the same time, I recognize that realistically you have no control over your neighbor's home, so the solution is most likely going to fall completely on you.

I think really the simplest way is to install screens on all your windows and have a second screen door installed on your outside doors.  Since you mentioned your cat is damaging screens to try to get out, you should use screens that are advertised as "pet-proof".  These screens are heavier than normal bug-screens, and so hopefully will be strong enough to keep your cat from damaging them.